# Why do I get "'OpenIDConnect' object has no attribute 'extra_data_serializer'" with Okta+oidc?

Tags: python, flask, okta, flask-oidc

I try to integrate Okta in my Flask application with [flask-oidc](https://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The [example app](https://github.com/okta/samples-python-flask/tree/master/okta-hosted-login) works fine with my `client_secrets.json`, but when I integrate this in my (larger) application, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/math/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/math/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/math/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_oidc/__init__.py", line 486, in decorated
    return self.redirect_to_auth_server(request.url)
  File "/home/math/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_oidc/__init__.py", line 550, in redirect_to_auth_server
    state[statefield] = self.extra_data_serializer.dumps(
AttributeError: 'OpenIDConnect' object has no attribute 'extra_data_serializer'
```

Interestingly, I only get this error when I try to access a view protected by `@oidc.require_login`. When I first login and then access the protected view, it works fine. I would have expected the redirect ([flask-oidc code](https://github.com/puiterwijk/flask-oidc/blob/master/flask_oidc/__init__.py#L480-L494)), just as it happens for the non-blueprint view.

How can I make blueprints directly work with flask-oidc?

Comment: Can you also post the code as well for the view and how the annotations have been used?

Comment: I have tested the example with the blueprints and it works fine. I think you may have incorrect order for annotations

Comment: "I think you may have incorrect order for annotations" - that is interesting. What would be the correct order?

Comment: Route one should be at the top and login required at bottom in terms of line ordering

Comment: @MartinThoma can you please post your sample code? The entire file where you initialize the flask app and the routes?